# Is it possible to use EventMachine to execute a method per day

Tags: ruby, events, scheduled-tasks

I need to rename a file each day but I am new to ruby and am lost on how to do it.

I have this method:

```
def self.start_server
  begin
    EventMachine.run {
      update_now
      start_servers
      EventMachine.add_periodic_timer(1) { update_now }
      EventMachine.add_periodic_timer(@config[:interval]) { write_queue }
      EventMachine.add_periodic_timer(@config[:syncinterval]) { flush_queue }
    }
  ensure
    cleanup
  end
end
```

Is it possible to add here something that would run once per day. A method that would rename a file to following format `<yyymmdd>.sqlite`.

Is it possible to make it work with this?

Comment: Running a job once every day sounds to me like a **cron** task.

Comment: @spickermann but I need it to be on the code, but the question actually is if it is possible with `EventMachine`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @spickermann, this is a cron's task.

You can manage your cron jobs from your ruby code with the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem. It is a dsl for configuring the recurring tasks of a ruby project.

This way you can keep all the needed configuration to your ruby code.

doc example:

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end

every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_four_thirty_in_the_morning"
end
```

Comment: But this needs to be on the `schedule.rb` right? not on my code?

Comment: How do I execute this?

Comment: That specific part yes. But it is inside your repository with the other components. Also you can have the parameters in your desired module/class and use it as configuration.

Comment: How can I make this start when my server gets started?

Comment: in the documentation there are some instructions about capistrano integration.